# How to dynamically update Locator[] constraints?

Tags: dynamic, manipulate, locator

I need to visualize [Menelaus' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus%27_theorem) for a triangle with moving locators for each of six points. So the vertexes of the triangle can move in any possible way, and the three points on the sides of the triangle can not - they should be fixed on the side.

I've tried manipulating stuff, but I cant merge the `Manipulate` with

```
Locator[Dynamic[pa1, (pa1 = ToTheLine[#, pb, pc]) &]]
```

So I've come to this:

```
ToTheLine[p_, lb_, le_] :=
  {
    p[[1]], 
    If[le[[1]] == lb[[1]],
      p[[2]],
      lb[[2]] - (lb[[1]] - p[[1]])*(le[[2]] - lb[[2]])/(le[[1]] - lb[[1]])]
  }

DynamicModule[{
  pa = {-5, 0}, pb = {5, 0}, pc = {0, 10},
  pa1 = (pb + pc)/2, pb1 = (pa + pc)/2, pc1 = (pb + pa)/2},
  (* point pa1 is labeled as D and is on side BC of the triangle, 
     similar definition for the others *)
  Graphics[{
      Locator[Dynamic[pa]], (* point A *)
      Locator[Dynamic[pb]], (* point B *)
      Locator[Dynamic[pc]], (* point C *)
      Locator[Dynamic[pa1, (pa1 = ToTheLine [#, pb, pc]) &]],
      Locator[Dynamic[pb1, (pb1 = ToTheLine [#, pc, pa]) &]],
      Locator[Dynamic[pc1, (pc1 = ToTheLine [#, pb, pa]) &]],
      Text[Style["A", 20, "Label"], Dynamic[pa + {0, 1}]],
      Text[Style["B", 20, "Label"], Dynamic[pb + {0, 1}]],
      Text[Style["C", 20, "Label"], Dynamic[pc + {0, 1}]],
      Text[Style["D", 10, "Label"], Dynamic[pa1 + {0, 1}]],
      Text[Style["E", 10, "Label"], Dynamic[pb1 + {0, 1}]],
      Text[Style["F", 10, "Label"], Dynamic[pc1 + {0, 1}]],
      Thick, Red, 
      Line [{Dynamic[pa], Dynamic[pb], Dynamic[pc], Dynamic[pa]}],
      Thin, Black,
      Line [{Dynamic[pa], Dynamic[pc1]}],
      Line [{Dynamic[pb], Dynamic[pa1]}],
      Line [{Dynamic[pc], Dynamic[pb1]}],
      Line [{Dynamic[pa1], Dynamic[pb1]}],
      Line [{Dynamic[pb1], Dynamic[pc1]}]},
    PlotRange -> 20.
    Axes -> True.
    ImageSize -> 600]]
```

The function `ToTheLine` just gets locator coords and puts the points on a line defined by two other points.

When I drag a point on the side and then drag vertex, the point doesnt stay on side anymore. I tried `Locator[Dynamic[pc1, (pc1 = ToTheLine [#, Dynamic[pb], Dynamic[pa]]) &]]`, which uses correct coords for A and B, but there is some error there.

How can I solve this problem? Is there a far more elegant solution?

Comment: There's a [demonstration](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/MenelausTheorem/) for it. But I'd agree that it's not always easy to understand the code of a demonstration...

Comment: i've seen the demonstration. but in that demonstration there are no constrained locators.

Comment: No worries, just thought it was worth a look if you hadn't seen it.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 7):

First I address the general solution, and below treat the particular case of your example.

Make a list of locators in a particular order such as

```
locators = { tri1, tri2, tri3, opp1, opp2, opp3 }
```

where the `tri` are the coordinates of the triangle and the `opp` are the coordinates of the points on the side opposite the respective vertex.  Note in Menelaus theorem, at least one point lies on the extension of a side.

Next, each time one of the locators is moved, the list of all six points needs to be updated.  I'd suggest using a function like

```
newConfig[loc_List, {{}}] := loc;
newConfig[loc_List, {{moved_}}] := ...
```

The variable `moved` will be the index (returned by `Position` below) of the locator in the list of points `loc` that moved.  The function `newConfig` would compute a new configuration depending on which one moved.  In your case, it could constrain the `opp` locators to lie on a  line.

The general structure of the `Manipulate` would be

```
Manipulate[
 LocatorPane[
  Dynamic[locators, (locators = newConfig[#, Position[locators - #, Except[{0., 0.}], {1}, 1, Heads -> False]]) &],
  Dynamic@Graphics[{(* graphics for figure *)}]
 ],
 {{locators, ..(* init.config.*)}, None}]
```

If you'd prefer `DynamicModule` you could use that instead of `Manipulate`, but it is possible to use `Manipulate`.

---

**Example: Menelaus' Theorem**

First, the configuration of the locators: the points are ordered so that
if `locator[[i]]` is a vertex of the triangle, then `locator[[i+3]]` is on the opposite side.

Second, whenever a locator is moved, two points need updating.  When the locator is a vertex of the triangle, the points are the nonvertices on the adjacent sides.  When the locator is a point on a side, the points are one of the other side points and the locator itself; which side point is arbitrary but determines the behavior.  Below, I made a cyclic choice so that the behavior has a somewhat symmetric feel.  Which points need updating when a given point is moved is encoded in the list of rules `$movedToUpdate`.

```
  (* moving a point causes others to need updating according to the following rules *)
$movedToUpdate = {1 -> {5, 6}, 2 -> {4, 6}, 3 -> {4, 5},
   4 -> {5, 4}, 5 -> {6, 5}, 6 -> {4, 6}};

  (* finds the intersection of a line = {p1, p2} and its conjugate, line+3 *)
lineEq[twopoints_] := 
  Det[Transpose[twopoints~Join~{{x, y}}]~Join~{{1, 1, 1}}] == 0;
intersection[points_, line_] :=
  {x, y} /. First@Solve[{lineEq[points[[line]]], lineEq[points[[line + 3]]]}, {x, y}];

  (* initial configuration of locators; last point determined by intersection *)
$initConfig = {{0., 0.5}, {-0.5, -0.5}, {0.5, -0.5}, {0.75, -0.5}, {0.25, 0.}};
$initConfig = $initConfig~Join~{intersection[$initConfig, {1, 2}]};

newConfig[locs_, {{}}] := locs; (* in case of dynamic update when no locators moved *)
newConfig[locs_, {{moved_}}] :=
 Fold[ReplacePart[#1, #2 -> intersection[#1, DeleteCases[Range[3], Mod[#2, 3, 1]]]] &,
      locs, moved /. $movedToUpdate];

Manipulate[
 LocatorPane[
  Dynamic[locators,
    (locators = newConfig[#, Position[locators - #, Except[{0., 0.}], {1}, 1, Heads -> False]]) &],
  Dynamic@Graphics[
    GraphicsComplex[locators,
     {Line[{{4, 2, 3}, {1, 5, 3}, {1, 2, 6}, {4, 5, 6}}],
      Red, Line[{1, 2, 3, 1}], PointSize[Large], Red, Point[Range[6]]}],
    PlotRange -> 1]
  ],
 {{locators, $initConfig}, None}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 6):

```
d = Dynamic;
s[{x_, i_, y_}] := Text[Style[x, 10 i, "Label"], Dynamic[y + {0, 1}]]
toLine[pt_, start_, end_] := Module[{param = ((pt-start).(end-start))/Norm[end-start]^2}, 
                                    start + Clip[param, {0, 1}] (end - start)]
DynamicModule[{
  pa  = {-5, 0},     pb = {5, 0},       pc  = {0, 10},
  pa1 = (pb + pc)/2, pb1 = (pa + pc)/2, pc1 = (pb + pa)/2},
 {Dynamic[pa1 = toLine[pa1, pb, pc]; pb1 = toLine[pb1, pa, pc]; pc1 = toLine[pc1, pb, pa];],
  Graphics[{
    s/@{{"A",2,d@pa},{"B",2,d@pb}, {"C",2,d@pc},{"D",1,d@pa1}, {"E",1,d@pb1}, {"F",1,d@pc1}},
    Thick, Red,  Line @ {d@pa, d@pb, d@pc, d@pa},
    Thin, Black, Line @ {d@pa, d@pc1, d@pb1, d@pc, d@pb1, d@pa1, d@pb},
    Locator /@          {d@pa, d@pc1, d@pb1, d@pc, d@pb1, d@pa1, d@pb},
    PlotRange -> 20, Axes -> True, ImageSize -> 600}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thx a lot, its great! But i cant still figure how does dynamic works properly ( What if we want to dynamically count the distance between, say, D and line EF? Where should i put the calculation? xd = pa1[[1]];
yd = pa1[[2]];
x1 =  pb1[[1]];
y1 = pb1[[2]];
x2 =  pc1[[1]];
y2 = pc1[[2]];
n = Normalize[{y1 - y2, x2 - x1, x1*y2 - x2*y1}];
dist = Norm[n*{xd, yd, 1}];

Comment: @I.Alexandrov In the DynMod vars add `pe` and replace the Dynamic for `Dynamic[
 pa1 = ToTheLine[pa1, pb, pc];
 pb1 = ToTheLine[pb1, pa, pc];
 pc1 = ToTheLine[pc1, pb, pa];
 pe = Norm[pa1 - ToTheLine[pa1, pb1, pc1]]]`

Comment: Just a side note: don't forget `Deploy@Graphics[...]`.

Comment: I'm surprised that both answers hadn't received any votes in almost a day...