# Moving a locator based on the movement of another

Tags: graphics, dynamic, gui-construction, locator

My problem is:

I want two `Locator`s to simulate a vector in the following sense:

- The first `Locator` is the base and the second the tip of the vector.
- When I move the tip, the base does not move (hence the vector changes).
- When I move the base, the vector is unchanged, and therefore the tip (and the `Locator`) moves.

How can I achieve that?

I have tried storing the previous value of the base and then test if the current value is different. And if so updated the position of the tip. I can however not make that work, when using 'Module'. I suspect that there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: This you look at the other related answers? Such as this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26891/locator-following-other-locator-in-dynamicmodule?rq=1

Comment: Also related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22134/how-to-dynamically-update-locator-constraints

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be a duplicate but I can't find it :). Meanwhile, you can use second argument of `Dynamic`.

```
x = {0, 0}; y = {1, 1}; w = y - x;


Deploy@Graphics[{
                 Locator@Dynamic[x, (x = #; y = x + w;) &],
                 Locator@Dynamic[y, (y = #; w = y - x;) &],
                 Dynamic@Arrow[{x, y}]
                }
                , PlotRange -> 2]
```

[image]

In case of multiple vectors one may want to save space and make code more transparent so we can use extended version of `Dynamic` second argument to achieve this:

```
Deploy@Graphics[{
                 Locator@Dynamic[x, {(w = y - x;) &, (x = #; y = x + w) &, None}],
                 Locator@Dynamic[y],
                 Dynamic@Arrow[{x, y}]
                }
               , PlotRange -> 2]
```

Now we are working only with base, moreover `w` can be scoped to particular `Locator`.

There is huge advantage of the second method, well, not exactly the method but the usage of `f_start` and `f_end`. You can calculate `w` once, not all the time you are dragging the `Locator`.

Comment: +1 I like this answer a lot and a learned something from it! btw. while I researched it I noticed that the exact number of times `w` is calculated in the second version is twice every time you drag that locator. (Method; first n=0; and then inside the anonymous function `Print[n++]`).

Comment: @Anon Indeed, I saw this too with `Print`. Do you know why it is so?

Comment: No! I became very curious but I suppose there is no good answer. It's not what is says in the documentation so I guess that's just "how it is".

Answer (score 4):

```
p1save = {0, 0}; p2save = {1, 1};
Manipulate[
        If[p1 != p1save, p2 = p2 + p1 - p1save; p1save = p1];
        Graphics[Arrow[{p1, p2}], PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, AspectRatio -> 1],
 {{p1, p1save}, Locator}, {{p2, p2save}, Locator}
 ]
```

or a little bit more sophisticated, preventing the arrow to overflow the graphics window:

```
p1save = {0, 0}; p2save = {1, 1};  min = -5; max = 5;
Manipulate[
 If[Or @@ ((min > # || # > max) & /@ Flatten[{p1, p2 + p1 - p1save}]),
                                               p1 = p1save; p2 = p2save];
 If[p1 != p1save, p2 = p2 + p1 - p1save; p1save = p1; p2save = p2];
 Graphics[Arrow[{p1, p2}], PlotRange -> {{min, max}, {min, max}},  AspectRatio -> 1],
 {{p1, p1save}, Locator}, {{p2, p2save}, Locator}
 ]
```

Comment: Looking good. But somehow in the second example if I move the base of the arrow, the head of the arrow moves at constant speed.