# Possible bug with second argument of Dynamic

Tags: dynamic, bugs, gui-construction

**Bug introduced in V9 or earlier and fixed in V10**

---

According to the [documentation, Dynamic Details & Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dynamic.html?q=Dynamic&lang=en) section, especially:

> For interactive mouse operations `Dynamic[expr,{f_start, f, f_end}]` **typically** evaluates `f_start[val,expr]` once when the mouse is pressed, then evaluates `f[val,expr]` whenever the mouse is moved, and then evaluates `f_end[val,expr]` once when the mouse is released.

I find the following behaviour a possible bug:

```
x = {.5, .5};
Graphics[{ Circle[],
           Locator[Dynamic[x, {Print[#] &, Automatic, None}]]
        }]
```

[image]

As you see `f_start = Print[#]&` is evaluated twice each time.

Is this a bug?

I've marked **Bold** the word **typically** in the quotation from documentation. Is this reffering to this case?

---

Here's the link to the question where [Anon](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/731/anon) and I have faced this issue for the first time:
[Moving a locator based on the movement of another](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30359/5478)

Comment: If you put `{Print["start"] &, Print["mid"] &, Print["end"] &}` inside the `Dynamic`, you will see, that there is a mouse-moved event (`"mid"`) registered between the two `"start"` events. I am still pondering on the significance of this detail...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Edit: fixed

---

Yes, it is a bug. I am quite confident it will be fixed in an upcoming release.

Comment: So you've faced it earlier and consulted with Wolfram?

Comment: I was considerably less confident than Rolf.  Especially when I tried it in a development build, and it behaved worse.  But then I fixed it.  So I guess my confidence matches Rolf's, now. :)  Beta testers should see this in the next beta build.

Comment: John for president!