# Why there is an extra node left behind?

Tags: graphics

I intend to add a node and an edge to a RandomGraph when clicking on one of its
existing nodes and drag the newly generated node to a new position. However, there always
an extra node left behind at the clicked node. What is wrong with the following codes? Please help.

```
DynamicModule[{ rg },
 rg = RandomGraph[{5, 8}] ;
 edglst = EdgeList[rg];
 vlst = VertexList[rg];
 VPOS = VertexCoordinates /. AbsoluteOptions[rg, VertexCoordinates];

 EventHandler[ 
  g = Dynamic@Graph[vlst, edglst, VertexCoordinates -> VPOS,
     VertexSize -> {.04, .04},
     VertexLabels -> "Name",
     PlotRange -> 2,
     EdgeStyle -> {Thick} ],
  {"MouseDown" :>  
    (pos = MousePosition["Graphics"]; 
     ind = Position[ VPOS, Nearest[ VPOS, pos][[1]]][[1, 1]];
     vnumb = Length[vlst] + 1;
     AppendTo[vlst, vnumb];
     AppendTo[VPOS, pos];
     AppendTo[edglst, ind <-> vnumb];
     ind = vnumb; ),
   "MouseDragged" :> ( VPOS [[ ind]] = MousePosition["Graphics"] )
   } ,
  PassEventsDown -> True 
   ]
 ]
```

@ Öskå  If the newly generated node is dragged to an existing node, I intend to joint the two nodes. Please note the following codes, so substitute `MouseDown` with `MouseClicked` seems not good enough in this intention.

```
DynamicModule[{rg}, rg = RandomGraph[{7, 10}];
 edglst = EdgeList[rg];
 vlst = VertexList[rg];
 OVP = VPOS = 
   VertexCoordinates /. AbsoluteOptions[rg, VertexCoordinates];

 EventHandler[g = Dynamic@Graph[vlst, edglst,
     VertexCoordinates -> VPOS,
     VertexSize -> {.04, .04},
     VertexLabels -> "Name",
     PlotRange -> 3,
     EdgeStyle -> {Thick}],
  {"MouseDown" :> (pos = MousePosition["Graphics"];
     ind = Position[VPOS, Nearest[VPOS, pos][[1]]][[1, 1]];
     tmp = ind;
     vnumb = Length[vlst] + 1;
     AppendTo[vlst, vnumb];
     AppendTo[VPOS, pos];
     AppendTo[edglst, ind <-> vnumb];
     ind = vnumb;),
   "MouseDragged" :> (VPOS[[ind]] = MousePosition["Graphics"]),
   "MouseUp" :> (pos2 = MousePosition["Graphics"];
     ind2 = Position[OVP, Nearest[OVP, pos2][[1]]][[1, 1]];
     vnumb = Length[vlst] ;
     vlst = Drop[vlst, -1];
     VPOS = Drop[VPOS, -1];
     edglst = Drop [edglst, -1];
     If[! (MemberQ[edglst, tmp <-> ind2] || MemberQ[edglst, ind2 <-> tmp]),
     AppendTo[edglst, tmp <-> ind2]];
      )
   },
  PassEventsDown -> True
  ]
 ]
```

Comment: I think this is the bug we are talking about: [32035](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32035/5478)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good question, and I remember talking to someone about this in another Q&A somewhere but I can't find it right now (Update: Kuba found the Q&A [about the bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32035/5478)). Some events fire twice for no apparent reason, and you have to build your own mechanism to avoid this unwanted behavior:

```
DynamicModule[{rg, refreshed = True}, rg = RandomGraph[{5, 8}];
 edglst = EdgeList[rg];
 vlst = VertexList[rg];
 VPOS = VertexCoordinates /. AbsoluteOptions[rg, VertexCoordinates];
 EventHandler[
  g = Dynamic@Graph[vlst, edglst, VertexCoordinates -> VPOS,
     VertexSize -> {.04, .04}, VertexLabels -> "Name",
     PlotRange -> 2, EdgeStyle -> {Thick}], {
   "MouseDown" :> (
     If[refreshed,
      pos = MousePosition["Graphics"];
      ind = Position[VPOS, Nearest[VPOS, pos][[1]]][[1, 1]];
      vnumb = Length[vlst] + 1;
      AppendTo[vlst, vnumb];
      AppendTo[VPOS, pos];
      AppendTo[edglst, ind <-> vnumb];
      ind = vnumb;
      refreshed = False
      ]
     ),
   "MouseDragged" :> (
     VPOS[[ind]] = MousePosition["Graphics"];
     refreshed = True
     )
   }, PassEventsDown -> True]
 ]
```

btw I would recommend localizing variables. You're already using `DynamicModule` so why not.

Comment: I've linked the thread you are thinking about. Which was motivated by you btw :)

Comment: @Pickett Thanks a lot. Yes, it is better to localize the variables.

Comment: @Kuba Yes, that's the one. Thanks.