# Response to user interaction inside Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, interface, interactive

I'd like to create a `Manipulate` with custom objects in the control area (like a circuit diagram) that reacts to the user interacting with the manipulate controls (e.g. highlighting the component being manipulated by the user).

Are there other functions/symbols besides `$ControlActiveSetting` (which does not discern which symbol is being manipulated) and `ControlActive` (which only evaluates to one of two things depending on wether the `act` in `ControlActive[act, norm]` is currently manipulated or not)? Ideally I'd like to have something like $ControlActiveSetting for individual symbols so that I can query those and change my display accordingly.

Comment: The second argument of `Dynamic` or `TrackingFunction` can be used to achieve such behavior.

Comment: @Kuba I tied `EventHandler` already but it seems to interfere with the behavior of `Slider`. Try `DynamicModule[{col = White, z}, 
 EventHandler[
  Slider[Dynamic@z, {0, 1}, 
   Background -> Dynamic@col], {"MouseDragged" :> (col = Red), 
   "MouseUp" :> (col = White)}]]`. If you remove the `"MouseUp"`-event the slider behaves as it should.

Comment: Add `PassEventsDown -> True` and it's fine. You can also use the second argument of `Dynamic`.

Comment: Cloud you prepare a code samples with desired effects you struggle to achieve?

Comment: I had a look at the second argument of `Dynamic` and the variant `Dynamic[expr, {f, fEnd}]` works like a charm once I looked it up. Even though this all is listed in the documentation and there are useful examples, I think it is easy to miss.

Comment: @Sascha Sure, documentation is huge. Do you want to provide an example, or maybe we can find a duplicate about synchornizing dynamic elements. Like here: [**30354**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30354/5478)

Comment: @Kuba Once I finish my work I'd gladly post it as an answer. I think it might be instructive to other users and seems not to be covered yet by other questions/answers about the second argument to `Dynamic`

Comment: Hard to say without examples but it's not new: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=second+argument+of+dynamic